# setTimeout inside Promise vs setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I know that a callback function inside `setTimeout()` will wait until the timer attached to it expires and the gets pushed into a callback queue. On the other hand, a promise, once fulfilled or rejected gets its callback pushed into a microtask queue, which has higher priority.

My question is which once is faster: a `setTimeout` inside a promise or a simple `setTimeout`. If the former one is not placed onto the microtask queue anymore, why is the `setTimeout` alone running first instead of the other way around?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 1000);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // This is run automatically, let's run resolve after 1 second
  setTimeout(() => resolve('promise!'), 1000);
});

promise.then(
  (result) => console.log(result),
  (err) => console.log(error)
);

// output: timeout -> promise || and not || promise -> timeout
```

Now let's suppose I forget the 1 second delay, now the promise will always appear first since the callback scheduled inside the microtask queue has higher priority

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // This is run automatically, let's run resolve after 1 second
  // setTimeout(() => resolve('promise!'), 1000);
  resolve('');
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('promise');
});
```

Comment: Faster? I would guess that there's absolutely no meaningful difference. You're waiting for a whole second anyway.

Comment: Let me update the question

Comment: Designing an application around how the runtime will schedule asynchronous happenings is an extremely bad idea. You have no guarantee that the timeout will be particularly close to 1000 milliseconds anyway.

Comment: In both cases the macrotask has to complete first. With the promise the macrotask results in queueing a microtask. But I'm not sure how that's at all useful.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Your edit actually made it less clear what issue you're trying to address.

Comment: I m not trying to solve any problem, I m just curious why the second example behaves how I expect it, whereas the first one doesn't.

Comment: Timeout callbacks are generally run in the order that they're received by the runtime, so in your first example the timeout in the Promise will fire *after* the timeout that's outside the Promise. They'll both be *scheduled* one after the other, microseconds apart.

Comment: Does that mean the callback inside my promise won't be attached to the microtask queue?

Comment: @newbie99 your first example is bound to the macrotask queue. Your second one isn't. I can pick up my glass and take a drink - that's a microtask. I can also order a glass of water from a waiter - that's a macrotask. If I order a glass of water, the waiter brings it, and I drink immediately, that's your plain timeout example. If I order a glass of water, the waiter brings it, I place it on the table, then pick it up and take a drink, that's your promise example. Which one do you think takes longer? Now if we eliminate the need for a waiter in the second case, which one would take longer?

Comment: "*Does that mean the callback inside my promise won't be attached to the microtask queue?*" the callback is ***not*** attached to any queue. The callback is running synchronously. The callback resolving the promise causes the handler to be queued on the microtask. If there is a `setTimeout` in the promise executor, then the timer has to be resolved normally as a macrotask.

Comment: @VLAZ is right. In the first code, there will be two `setTimeout()` calls in very rapid succession. The runtime will queue them up in the timer queue. The one that was requested first will fire first, and the one requested second will fire afterwards. That the second `setTimeout()` call is inside a Promise callback makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense...a little for now. Does anyone want to respond so I can vote up the answer?

Comment: @Pointy right, I think I didn't explain it quite well. The "timeout" and "promise" tasks both go into the macrotask queue in this order. First "timeout" then "promise". Therefore, they would finish in this order. When "timeout" finishes, it logs again *synchronously*. When "promise" finishes, it resolves the promise, which will *asynchronously* trigger the log. Therefore, this example is a roundabout `console.log("timeout"); Promise.resolve("promise").then(console.log)` - the "timeout" will always log first.

Comment: I think you made it more confusing, since for the Event Loop timers have low precedence, which means that anything in the microtask queue have to finish before something in the timer queue can schedule for execution in the call stack. My first example was bad because, as @Pointy pointed out, I was using a setTimeout (in the promise) which scheduled my callback in the timer queue, in sequence, after the first setTimeout, and thus the results.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is implemented in a way it's meant to execute after a minimum given delay, and once the browser's thread is free to execute it. so, for an example, if you specify a value of 0 for the delay parameter and you think it will execute "immediately", it won't. it will, more accurately, run in the next event cycle (which is part of the event loop - concurrency model which is responsible for executing the code).

Let's take the example for a delay value of 0.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('promise!'), 0);
});

promise.then(
  (result) => console.log(result),
  (err) => console.log(error)
);
```

The `setTimeout` will always log it's result first because it will execute surely in the next event cycle.

The `setTimeout` in the promise on the other hand, will have 2 event cycles until the console log will execute (one for the promise resolve and the other one for the callback in the setTimeout function).

Please read reason for delays longer then specified - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

More about the JS event loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 1):

The key takeaway is

> Each time a task exits, the event loop checks to see if the task is returning control to other JavaScript code. If not, it runs all of the microtasks in the microtask queue.

In your first example below, once the task of executing the main program exits, there isn't any microtask to be processed because the promise hasn't been resolved yet due to the 2nd setTimeout. Then the task queue gets processed, so 'timeout' is logged first. After that, the 2nd setTimeout is processed and promise is resolved and then the resolved result is printed in the console.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 1000);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // This is run automatically, let's run resolve after 1 second
  setTimeout(() => resolve('promise!'), 1000);
});

promise.then(
  (result) => console.log(result),
  (err) => console.log(error)
);

// output: timeout -> promise || and not || promise -> timeout
```

Whereas in your second example, the promise is resolved once the task executing the main program exits, so the microtask queue gets processed first and logs 'promise'. The task queue is then processed after and logs 'timeout'.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // This is run automatically, let's run resolve after 1 second
  // setTimeout(() => resolve('promise!'), 1000);
  resolve('');
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('promise');
});
```

I highly recommend to read through [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#tasks_vs._microtasks), which helps me understand in depth on how task queue and microtask queue work.